# Docker deploy on specific container

Tags: docker, deployment, environment, production, staging

I have an issue, i want to know how can i do that ?

I should have single source code and I should be running multiple containers on basis of that single source code.
e.g staging, development, production

I will be doing changes on my local machine and when I am done testing on my local machine, and when I am satisfied, i should choose on which environment i want to deploy

e.g I only want to deploy on staging server, not on production.

E.g If i make changes on my source code files , it should not affect my containers on production.

How can i achieve that with a single source code file for my multiple runnig containers on different environments.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you include an example of your current deployment setup?  You should be able to build and push an image with your updated application, and selectively upgrade the containers in specific environments.

Comment: I am currently trying on my local machine.

I have a source file named "index.php" 

I have 3 containers ( php:7.2-apache )


They are all working on the same ( index.php) source file which is physically located on my host machine.

I mounted volumes like this in my 3 containers: 

./src:/var/www/html

I have no issue with ports and volumes.

My issue is, i want to make changes in my source file , but i don't want the changes to be applied in 1 of the 3 containers for example.
Considering that the one of these 3 containers is on production.

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question and comment that you have 1 source code and 3 stages right?
You can't do this with the shared volume you can try to copy your code from local dir to inside the container during the build using this step

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . .
```

Also, you say that you need to do this on the production stage my question to you
will you use one server for all stages (development/staging/production)?

Comment: I will use one server for all stages (development/staging/production).  Is there no other option than copying code inside the container ? I have like 15gb of code on my local machine.  Suppose i build the image with code inside. After 2 days i update my code , i will rebuild an image ( version 2) and when building the image , it will copy all the code or only changings between v1 and v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

As already earlier mentioned by Thabet you probably want to build your own docker image and copy your file(s) there.
Create your own Dockerfile and build an image. See also the docs https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#building-the-apps-container-image

If you would like to update your files on production you rebuild your image, and use the latest version of your image on production.